# Match CSV Values to Make Dictionary Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've been trying to make an auto-correct and -complete program and trying to make it more useful using a frequency algorithm using CSV, but am pretty new to using CSV files. I'm trying to create a dictionary from a CSV file that I can then use to determine the top results.

The CSV file contains of 1/3 of a million lines, sorted from highest frequency to lowest. It starts with the two item categories, "word" and "count", followed by 333,333 lines.

```
word,count
the,23135851162
of,13151942776
and,12997637966
to,12136980858
a,9081174698
in,8469404971
for,5933321709
is,4705743816
on,3750423199
```

Using the file, which can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rtatman/english-word-frequency), I am trying to create a dictionary like so:

```py
{"the":23135851162, "of":13151942776, "and":12997637966, "to":12136980858, etc.}
```

I've tried using the following script using the pandas library like so,

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("./unigram_freq.csv")
wordFreq = {col: list(data[col]) for col in data.columns}
```

but end up with a dictionary output that looks something like the following.

```py
{'word': ['the', 'of', 'and', 'to', etc.], 'count':[23135851162, 13151942776, 12997637966, 12136980858, etc.]}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you update me a little on what you are trying to do next with your data? Converting CSV to Dict format is easy enough and I can walk you through the process. However I have a feeling the Pandas (as you guessed already) will be a more suitable option for you.

Comment: try just `wordFreq = dict(zip(data['word'], data['count']))`

Comment: @ARK1375 I am planning on taking an incomplete or incorrect word and returning the three best suitable answers. The frequency will help to suggest more oftenly used words instead of returning words like "aaa" just because it is the third word when sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question.  You can answer your own question below.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close - <kbd>`dict(zip(*[data[col] for col in data.columns]))`</kbd> would have worked, but it's probably better to be more specific when you [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the two columns together so that they become a list of key-value pairs that can be converted into a dictionary:

```py
wordFreq = dict(zip(data['word'], data['count'])) ## same as:
# wordFreq = {k:v for k,v in zip(data['word'], data['count'])}
```

---

Or you could make use of the [`<DataFrame>.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) function like

```py
wordFreq = dict(data.to_dict('split')['data'])
```

Although, if you had more than two columns (or if they were in a different order), you'd need to specify which column to use for keys and which for values:

```py
wordFreq = dict(data.set_index('word')['count']) ## series with index ## OR
# wordFreq = dict(data[['word', 'count']].to_dict('split')['data']) ## list of lists
```